# cordova media plugin. continue recording of existing

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, cordova-media-plugin

### background

I have an app which has build in voice recorder using `cordova-media-plugin`.
Nominally I can record and save a file.

### problem

When I am recording and I close app (without `instance.stopRecord()`) then file created, record but not saving correct. I can open it but i can't play it.

Does anybody know  how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you already tried to use a [pause-event-handler](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.pause.html#full-example)? Within this function you can call instance.stopRecord()

Comment: yes. I thought about it . But the problem is my app can record in background mode(when app at home screen)

Comment: Ok, then you have to use a button (or some kind of control) to enable/disable background-recording because there is no "close"-event in cordova and pause is fired when app is just put into background or really closed, so you can not distinguish between both "events". Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside cordova media plugin. I just added cordova onWillTerminate event to the CDVSound.m and just  stop recording when event fired.

**If somebody have the same problem here is the link on my patch - ** [Patch Link](https://app.box.com/s/mkh71fr8mymde02mqlusbjbhcpi6lufu)

P.S. - I'm not ios developer. And yes i know that possible to do it more clean. Thanks guys for help.